# convert dictionaries into string python

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I am trying to convert dictionaries into string

for example:

```
a={3:4,5:6}
s='3 4, 5 6'
```

The way I am trying is

```
s=''
i=0
for (k,v) in d.items():
    s=s+str(k)+' '+str(v)
    while i < len(s):
        if s[i]==str(v) and s[i+1]==str(k):
            s+=s+s[i]+','+s[i+1]
```

Comment: Do you actually want **that** format? Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a Pythonic way of doing that using a [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
s = ', '.join([str(x) + ' ' + str(a[x]) for x in a])
```

**Output:**

```
'3 4, 5 6'
```

**Update:** As [Julien Spronck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2184364/julien-spronck) mentioned, the square brackets (`[` and `]`) are not necessary. Thus, the following has the same effect:

```
s = ', '.join(str(x) + ' ' + str(a[x]) for x in a)
```

---

[**Working PythonFiddle**](http://pythonfiddle.com/dict-to-string)

Comment: turns out you type faster ☺

Comment: you don't need the square brackets, which would then make a generator expression

Answer (score 3):

You can write the *list comprehension* expression to get the list of key-value string, then join them on `,` as

```
>>> d = {3:4,5:6}
>>> ', '.join('{} {}'.format(k, v) for k, v in d.items())
'3 4, 5 6'
```

OR, even using [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr) (*Note: it is a hack, I consider `.join()` approach more pythonic*):

```
>>> repr(d)[1:-1].replace(':', '')
'3 4, 5 6'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following with a list comprehension:

```
', '.join([str(k) + ' ' + str(v) for k, v in a.items()])
```

To illustrate:

```
In [1]: a = {3:4, 5:6}

In [2]: s = ', '.join([str(k) + ' ' + str(v) for k, v in a.items()])

In [3]: s
Out[3]: '3 4, 5 6'
```

Comment: I actually like this better than my answer since it avoids the awkward use of `a[x]`.

Comment: @SumnerEvans I prefer this way as well, but your answer is actually more succinct than mine, and there is certainly something to be said for that. Does yours also perhaps perform better since it doesn't have the extra function call to `items()`?

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure how dictionaries are stored in the background, I'm assuming they are just a set of tuples, so retrieving them should be fairly efficient, maybe even more efficient than retrieving the keys and then retrieving the values. I'm not familiar enough with the library to say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Of course the most pythonic solution is the one using the list comprehension (see @SumnerEvans and the rest) but just for the sake of having an alternative i will post this here:

```
a = {3: 4, 5: 6}

v = str(a)
for rep in ['{', '}', ':']:
    v = v.replace(rep, '')
print(v)  # prints -> 3 4, 5 6
```

Everything can be converted into a string and the manipulated as one. This is what is being done here. From `dict` to `string` and then chained `replace` methods.

Comment: Can you speak to the efficiency of this vs list comprehension?

Comment: my hunch tells me the list comprehension is much faster but i cannot `timeit` now since i am at work.. Feel free to try though.

Answer (score 0):

You can still have it like this

```
s=''
i=0
a={3:4,5:6}
for (k,v) in a.items():
    if i < len(a) and s == '':
        s = s + str(k) + ' '+ str(v)
    elif i < len(a) and s != '':
        s += ", " + str(k) + ' '+ str(v)
    i += 1
    print(s)
```

This should give you

```
s='3 4, 5 6'
```